# Does XGBoost do sampling in evaluation when setting scale_pos_weight?

Tags: machine-learning, xgboost

Does XGB also do class-balancing sampling as training in the evaluation process when I assign a value to `scale_pos_weight`?

Here's a setting for example:

```
Classifier = XGBClassifier(objective="binary:logistic",n_jobs=4,scale_pos_weight=10) 
Classifier.fit(train_features, train_labels,eval_metric="aucpr",eval_set=[(train_features,train_labels),(test_features,test_labels)])
```

Does it do sampling on my `(test_features,test_labels)`?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following approaches:

```
neg, pos = np.bincount(train_labels)
print(np.bincount(train_labels))
import math 
class_weight1 = math.sqrt(neg/pos) 
print(class_weight1)
class_weight2 = neg/pos
print(class_weight2)
``
```

Classifier =XGBClassifier(random_state=0, scale_pos_weight=class_weight1)

```
It will resampling the classes in training set only. Resampling techniques are not applicable to test set.
```